# How to plot the DFT transformation of a vector with tikz/pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, r, vector, transformation

My question seems to be simple but still I could not find any answer for that. Assume that we have a vector and its `DFT` which I computed it in `R`.

```
> x <- c(3,9,4,2,5,6,2,6)
> x
[1] 3 9 4 2 5 6 2 6
> fft(x)
[1] 37.000000+0.000000i  2.949747-1.292893i  2.000000-7.000000i -6.949747+2.707107i -9.000000+0.000000i -6.949747-2.707107i  2.000000+7.000000i  2.949747+1.292893i
```

I stored the DFT coefficients in `input.txt`. Now, I want to plot these complex numbers stored in `input.txt` with `tikz/pgfplots`. I read [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512338/pgf-plots-complex-numbers), but it is just based on the exponential form of the complex numbers. So, I have no idea if it is possible to draw the plot without converting the complex numbers to the exponential form.

Comment: Hi and welcome. What are DFT coefficients?

Comment: Hi, take a look at here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform. @AndréC

Comment: It's better when you make it clear. Thank you. In french it's [TFD](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_de_Fourier_discrète)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this as well but I'm pretty sure you will find the [sagetex](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetex.pdf) package can handle this without any problems. It relies on the open source CAS, called Sage, which can handle Python, R, numpy, and much more. Discrete Fourier Transform documentation [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/calculus/transforms/dft.html). I can easily get your coefficients with Sage and I've created a plot. It doesn't look like the plot you linked to below though.

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

I don't know if this is the type of plot that you are looking for, but anyway the file `MWE.Rnw` below should serve to get the idea of the alternative way to obtain your desired plot with  `knitr`.

**MWE.Rnw**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<myplot,dev='tikz', echo=F,warning=F, fig.height=3, fig.width=3>>=
x <- c(3,9,4,2,5,6,2,6)    
plot(sort(x),sort(fft(x)),type='l',col="red",
xlab="$x$",ylab="\\texttt{fft($x$)}")
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am looking for a plot like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLhB7.png

Comment: @ThisIsMe, please edit your question and make it more clear. For example add above comment to it.